# Creating temporary tables in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, temp-tables

I am trying to create a temporary table that selects only the data for a certain `register_type`. I wrote this query but it does not work:

```
$ CREATE TABLE temp1
(Select 
    egauge.dataid,
    egauge.register_type,
    egauge.timestamp_localtime,
    egauge.read_value_avg
from rawdata.egauge
where register_type like '%gen%'
order by dataid, timestamp_localtime ) $
```

I am using PostgreSQL.
Could you please tell me what is wrong with the query?

Answer (score 109):

You probably want [**`CREATE TABLE AS`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtableas.html) - also works for `TEMPORARY` (`TEMP`) tables:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE temp1 AS
SELECT dataid
     , register_type
     , timestamp_localtime
     , read_value_avg
FROM   rawdata.egauge
WHERE  register_type LIKE '%gen%'
ORDER  BY dataid, timestamp_localtime;
```

This creates a temporary table and copies data into it. A *static snapshot* of the data, mind you. It's just like a regular table, but resides in RAM if `temp_buffers` is set high enough. It is only visible within the current *session* and dies at the end of it. When created with `ON COMMIT DROP` it dies at the end of the *transaction*.

Temp tables come first in the default **schema search path**, hiding other visible tables of the same name unless schema-qualified:

- [How does the search_path influence identifier resolution and the "current schema"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9067335/how-does-the-search-path-influence-identifier-resolution-and-the-current-schema/9067777#9067777)

---

If you want *dynamic*, you would be looking for [**`CREATE VIEW`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createview.html) - a completely different story.

---

The SQL standard also defines, and Postgres also supports: <strike>[`SELECT INTO`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-selectinto.html)</strike>. [But its use is discouraged](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-selectinto.html#AEN78092):

> It is best to use `CREATE TABLE AS` for this purpose in new code.

There is really no need for a second syntax variant, and `SELECT INTO` is used for assignment in `plpgsql`, where the SQL syntax is consequently not possible.

Related:

- [Combine two tables into a new one so that select rows from the other one are ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15559090/combine-two-tables-into-a-new-one-so-that-select-rows-from-the-other-one-are-ign/15560009#15560009)
- [ERROR: input parameters after one with a default value must also have defaults in Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24038195/error-input-parameters-after-one-with-a-default-value-must-also-have-defaults/24072348#24072348)

---

[**`CREATE TABLE LIKE (...)`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html) only copies the *structure* from another table and no data:

> The `LIKE` clause specifies a table from which the new table
>   automatically copies all column names, their data types, and their
>   not-null constraints.

---

If you need a "temporary" table just for the purpose of a single query (and then discard it) a **"derived table"** in a CTE or a subquery comes with considerably less overhead:

- [Change the execution plan of query in postgresql manually?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14982120/change-the-execution-plan-of-query-in-postgresql-manually/14983685#14983685)
- [Combine two SELECT queries in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15849423/combine-two-select-queries-in-postgresql/15850396#15850396)
- [Reuse computed select value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21863163/reuse-computed-select-value/21863334#21863334)
- [Multiple CTE in single query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35248217/multiple-cte-in-single-query/35249370#35249370)
- [Update with results of another sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25350431/update-with-results-of-another-sql/25354243#25354243)

Comment: Probably you just copied that query from question, but still asking: does `ORDER  BY` have any sense with `CREATE TEMP TABLE temp1 AS ..` ?

Comment: @OtoShavadze: It does. While it makes no difference logically, it determines the physical order of the inserted rows, which can have a substantial impact on performance, even with temp tables in RAM.

Comment: Ok understand, did not know that  physical order of the   rows can affect performance though.  Thank you

Comment: Can you alias a temp table in Postgres?

Comment: @tdelozie Yes. Given you mean the same "alias" as I do. Please ask your question as new *question* with the necessary details to be clear.

Answer (score 6):

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-createtable.html

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE temp1 LIKE ...
```

Comment: `CREATE [TEMP] TABLE <target-table> LIKE <source-table>` creates the table but does not populate it with data, so that is not what the OP has asked about.