# Combine two SELECT queries in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, union, common-table-expression

I would like to combine two select queries with `UNION`.
How can I use the result from the first `SELECT` in the second `SELECT`?

```
(SELECT carto_id_key FROM table1
    WHERE tag_id = 16)
UNION 
(SELECT * FROM table2
    WHERE carto_id_key = <the carto_id result from above> )
```

Comment: what do you actually want to achieve, this can be with a simple JOIN or a Subquery (if you just wish to get the required details), also the columns both of your queries dont match !!

Comment: I want to get all the records in table2 that meet the condition of the first SELECT

Comment: if that's the only requirement, read http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/tutorial-join.html

Comment: After looking at that documentation I found the best solution to be:

SELECT *
FROM tabl1 INNER JOIN table2 ON 
(table1. carto_id_key = table2. carto_id_key)
WHERE table2.tag_id = 16

thanks for the help

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Use a [**CTE**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html) to reuse the result from a subquery in more than one `SELECT`.

```
WITH cte AS (SELECT carto_id_key FROM table1 WHERE tag_id = 16)

SELECT carto_id_key
FROM   cte

UNION ALL
SELECT t2.some_other_id_key
FROM   cte
JOIN   table2 t2 ON t2.carto_id_key = ctex.carto_id_key
```

You most probably want [`UNION ALL`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-UNION) instead of `UNION`. Doesn't exclude duplicates and is faster this way.

Comment: Nice.  I just tried this and found that for `UNION ALL` to work, both of the SELECT statements had to return the same number of columns, with the same data types.