# How to add UNIQUE constraint to return column of a function?

Tags: postgresql, duplicates, unique, plpgsql

I need to add unique constraint to the `urls` column:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myFunction()  RETURNS TABLE(urls  TEXT)
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
DECLARE
--my code
BEGIN
END;
```

How to make `urls` column unique?

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [**no screen shots**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). **[edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Comment: what makes you think, you need function for it?..

Comment: i dont want to create new table .

Comment: You can not apply any constraints to the function's result directly (except of natural constraints of the type returned). Make sure that the values are unique inside the function's body.

Comment: I want get results of other table with batch queries not at once  and return unique results

Comment: to resolve the issue can i create temporary table ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want get results of other table with batch queries not at once and return unique results

It's not possible to add a `UNIQUE` constraint to the return type of a function like you can do it in a table definition.

You could use `UNION` (not `UNION ALL`) to get unique URLs like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myfunction()
  RETURNS TABLE(url TEXT) AS  -- singular term "url" makes more sense
$func$
BEGIN

RETURN QUERY
SELECT url FROM ...
UNION
SELECT url FROM ...
-- more?
;

END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

This is an SQL feature and you wouldn't need PL/pgSQL for the single `UNION` query. Nor even a function. A plain (sub-)query or a `VIEW` are alternatives.

Related:

- [PostgreSQL combine multiple select statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11828772/postgresql-combine-multiple-select-statements/11833128#11833128)
- [Combine two SELECT queries in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15849423/combine-two-select-queries-in-postgresql/15850396#15850396)
- [Function to loop through and select data from multiple tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24618672/function-to-loop-through-and-select-data-from-multiple-tables/24621496#24621496)

***Or*** you just return everything from the function:

```
...
RETURN QUERY SELECT url FROM ...;
RETURN QUERY SELECT url FROM ...;
-- more ?
...
```

and de-duplicate the result in the ***call*** like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT url FROM myfunction();
```

> To resolve the issue can I create temporary table?

You *can*. But be aware ...

- that's more expensive.
- if you define the column `UNIQUE`, an exception is raised and the whole transaction is rolled back if the constraint is violated.
- to avoid raising an exception use `INSERT .. ON CONFLICT (url) DO NOTHING`. More:

  - [Can INSERT [...] ON CONFLICT be used for foreign key violations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36038751/can-insert-on-conflict-be-used-for-foreign-key-violations/36039580#36039580)