# How to combine/merge two select queries by COLUMN in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would like to combine/merge two select queries by COLUMN and not by rows as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15849423/combine-two-select-queries-in-postgresql) with UNION.

Let`s say I have

```
SELECT attr1, attr2 FROM table1
```

and

```
SELECT attr1, attr2 FROM table2
```

Note, that both tables have the same Attribute Names.

And I want a result with following columns:

```
attr1_table1, attr2_table1, attr1_table2, attr2_table2
```

**Edit (just for the next as the outer join worked fine):**

My first Select Returns something like:

```
id  attr1  attr2
1   3      5
2   4      6
```

and my second select

```
id  attr1 attr2
1   7     9
2   8     10
```

And my desired result is:

```
id  attr1 attr2 attr1 attr2
1   3     5     7     9
2   4     6     8     10
```

Thanks

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: you are looking for join I believe?.. do you want a cartesian product of two, or combined values somehow?..

Comment: How do you want to choose which rows to line up from each table? A few rows of sample input ***and*** output data resolves this ambiguity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A cross join would be very dangerous because it produces a huge amount of data. E.g. if Table1 and Table2 each have 1000 rows, the result of a cross join would be 1,000,000 rows!

However, I assume you want to line up matching rows. So use the following:

```
select  COALESCE(t1.id, t2.id) as id,
        t1.attr1, t1.attr2, t2.attr1, t2.attr2
from    Table1 t1
        full outer join Table2 t2 on
            t2.id = t1.id
```

The `full outer join` means this also returns rows where no match is found.

Comment: adding `COALESCE(t1.id, t2.id) as id, `would make it complete.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is rather vague.  But one possible answer is a `cross join`:

```
select t1.attr1 as attr1_1, t1.attr2 as attr2_1,
       t2.attr1 as attr1_2, t2.attr2 as attr2_2
from table1 t1 cross join
     table2 t2;
```

Comment: What is the different between **table1** and **t1** in from? Aren't both the table name? And therefore only once needed?

Comment: @N.Varela `t1` and `t2` are aliases defined in the `FROM` clause. You don't need them because you could write `table1.attr1 as attr1_1` etc. But the aliases reduce the code needed to disambiguate the source table.