# Reuse computed select value

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis, explain, postgresql-performance

I'm trying to use [ST_SnapToGrid](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_SnapToGrid.html) and then `GROUP BY` the grid cells (x, y). Here is what I did first:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(*)                      AS n,
  ST_X(ST_SnapToGrid(geom, 50)) AS x,
  ST_Y(ST_SnapToGrid(geom, 50)) AS y
FROM points
GROUP BY x, y
```

I don't want to recompute `ST_SnapToGrid` for both `x` and `y`. So I changed it to use a sub-query:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(*)   AS n,
  ST_X(geom) AS x,
  ST_Y(geom) AS y
FROM (
  SELECT 
      ST_SnapToGrid(geom, 50) AS geom
  FROM points
) AS tmp
GROUP BY x, y
```

But when I run `EXPLAIN`, both of these queries have the exact same execution plan:

```
GroupAggregate  (...)
  ->  Sort  (...)
        Sort Key: (st_x(st_snaptogrid(points.geom, 0::double precision))), (st_y(st_snaptogrid(points.geom, 0::double precision)))
        ->  Seq Scan on points  (...)
```

**Question**: Will PostgreSQL reuse the result value of `ST_SnapToGrid()`?
If not, is there a way to make it do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Test timing

You don't see the evaluation of individual functions per row in the `EXPLAIN` output.

Test with `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` to get actual query times to compare overall effectiveness. Run a couple of times to rule out caching artifacts. For simple queries like this, you get more reliable numbers for the total runtime with:

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, TIMING OFF) SELECT ...
```

Requires Postgres **9.2+**. [Per documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-explain.html):

> `TIMING`
>
> Include actual startup time and time spent in each node in the output. The overhead of repeatedly reading the system clock can slow
>   down the query significantly on some systems, so it may be useful to
>   set this parameter to `FALSE` when only actual row counts, and not exact
>   times, are needed. Run time of the entire statement is always
>   measured, even when node-level timing is turned off with this option.
>   This parameter may only be used when `ANALYZE` is also enabled. It
>   defaults to `TRUE`.

#### Prevent repeated evaluation

Normally, expressions in a subquery are evaluated *once*. But Postgres can collapse trivial subqueries if it thinks that will be faster.

To introduce an optimization barrier, you could use a [**CTE**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-with.html) instead of the subquery. This *guarantees* that Postgres computes `ST_SnapToGrid(geom, 50)` once only:

```
WITH cte AS (
   SELECT ST_SnapToGrid(geom, 50) AS geom1
   FROM   points
   )
SELECT COUNT(*)   AS n
     , ST_X(geom1) AS x
     , ST_Y(geom1) AS y
FROM   cte
GROUP  BY geom1;         -- see below
```

However, this it's probably *slower* than a subquery due to more overhead for a CTE. The function call is probably very cheap. Generally, Postgres knows better how to optimize a query plan. Only introduce such an optimization barrier if you know better.

#### Simplify

I changed the name of the computed point in the subquery / CTE to `geom1` to clarify it's different from the original `geom`. That helps to clarify the **more important** thing here:

```
GROUP BY geom1
```

instead of:

```
GROUP BY x, y
```

That's obviously cheaper - and may have an influence on whether the function call is repeated. So, this is probably fastest:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS n
     , ST_X(ST_SnapToGrid(geom, 50)) AS x
     , ST_y(ST_SnapToGrid(geom, 50)) AS y
FROM   points
GROUP  BY ST_SnapToGrid(geom, 50);         -- same here!
```

Or maybe this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)    AS n
     , ST_X(geom1) AS x
     , ST_y(geom1) AS y
FROM (
   SELECT ST_SnapToGrid(geom, 50) AS geom1
   FROM   points
   ) AS tmp
GROUP  BY geom1;
```

Test all three  with `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` or `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, TIMING OFF)` and see for yourself. Testing >> guessing.