# How to update some columns with the same expression/value

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

I would like something like this:

```sql
UPDATE tab1
   SET name = descr = proc1(name)
 WHERE id &lt 1000
```

unlike double calling:

```sql
UPDATE tab1
   SET name = proc1(name),
       descr = proc1(name)
 WHERE id &lt 1000
```

Is that possible?

Comment: [Very similar question just yesterday.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21863163/reuse-computed-select-value)

Comment: Cool answer. Unfortunatelly CTE is not applicable to UPDATE.

Comment: But it is (since Postgres 9.1). Have a look at [the manual here.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING) [Related answer with complex example.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19413254/optimize-insert-update-delete-operation/19439591#19439591)

Comment: Yes you right I use 8.4. Alas. May be next year we will upgrade to 9.x. May be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not as you write. I assume that `proc1` is expensive/time consuming to invoke? If so, you may be able to use a subquery, at the cost of doing an additional join:

```
UPDATE tab1
SET name = p.p1n
    descr = p.p1n
FROM (
    SELECT id, proc1(name)
    FROM tab1
) p(id, p1n)
WHERE tab1.id = p.id
AND   tab1.id < 1000;
```

Comment: proc1 is regex_replace. It is not very expensive. So double call is twice quicker than self-joining.