# How to create Temporary table with AS in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
Create Temporary Table Temp3 ( 
user_id int not null,
) AS query(
select id 
from users
)
```

I use the above code in postgresql but it says:

ERROR:  syntax error at or near ")"
LINE 3: ) AS (
        ^

********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near ")"
SQL state: 42601
Character: 55

**How can I fix it to do the same job? Thx ahead!**

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15691243/creating-temporary-tables-in-sql

Comment: Is it really that hard to read the manual? http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtableas.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is much simpler than your try:

```
create temporary table Temp3 as
    select id as user_id
    from users;
```

See[`CREATE TABLE AS`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-createtableas.html)