# ERROR: input parameters after one with a default value must also have defaults in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, default-value

I am trying to set `default` value to a variable within the `function` in `parameter` list but getting an error:

> ERROR: input parameters after one with a default value must also have defaults

#### Example:

```
 Create or replace function test(name varchar default null
                               , city varchar default null
                               , phonenumber varchar(20) default null
                               , out sno bigint, address varchar)
   returns void as
 $$
 Declare 
        phonenumber AS VarChar(20);
 Begin
        phonenumber : =phonenumber; 
  
    SELECT sno = MAX(ssno)+1 FROM emp;

    IF(sno IS NULL)  then
           sno=IDENT_CURRENT('emp')+1;
    end;
    
    raise info '%',name;
    raise info '%',city;
    raise info '%',phonenumber;
    raise info '%',address;

    insert into emp(ename,ecity,ephonenumber,eaddress)
    values(name,city,phonenumber,address);

 end;
 $$
 langauge plpgsql;
```

Comment: Try setting default values for the last two parameters, or changing the order of parameters so the ones with default values are the last ones.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Much is not right in your example. Or rather: not much *is* right in your example.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_test(
     name text = NULL
   , city text = NULL
   , phonenumber text = NULL
    ,address text = NULL
   , OUT sno bigint)
RETURNS void AS
 $func$
DECLARE 
    phonenumber AS VarChar(20);  -- would collide with parameter name
BEGIN
phonenumber := phonenumber;      -- nonsense

SELECT INTO sno  max(ssno) + 1 FROM emp;  -- SELECT INTO for assignment

IF sno IS NULL THEN
  sno := ident_current('emp') + 1;
END IF;

RAISE NOTICE '%, %, %, %', name, city, phonenumber, address;

INSERT INTO emp(ename, ecity, ephonenumber, eaddress)
VALUES (name, city, phonenumber, address);

END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

#### Major points

- The error message speaks for itself:

  > input parameters after one with a default value must also have defaults.

  That's almost [what the manual has on that](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createfunction.html):

  > All input parameters following a parameter with a default value must
  >   have default values as well.
- It wouldn't make sense to combine `RETURNS void` with `OUT` parameters.
- Don't declare variable names colliding with parameter names. Completely useless here.
- The [plpgsql assignment operator is `:=`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7462322/the-forgotten-assignment-operator-and-the-commonplace), not `=`.
- You don't normally use the `RAISE` level `INFO`. You want `NOTICE` instead.
- `SELECT` without target is not possible in plpgsql, you want `SELECT INTO`.
- `IF` is terminated with `END IF` not with `END`.

#### Simplify further

Use [`COALESCE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL) to replace your `IF` statement. Aggregate functions return a row even if the table is empty.
But you don't need that either. Just use the `RETURNING` clause to return the new id directly:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_test(
     name text = NULL
   , city text = NULL
   , phonenumber text = NULL
   , address text = NULL
   , OUT sno bigint)
AS
$func$
BEGIN
RAISE NOTICE '%, %, %, %', name, city, phonenumber, address;

INSERT INTO emp(ename, ecity, ephonenumber, eaddress)
VALUES (name, city, phonenumber, address)
RETURNING ssno
INTO   sno;             -- Assuming you want to return autoincremented id 

END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Great Stuff! Finally got cleared with all errors. Thank you so much.

Comment: Is there Ident_current() function in PostgreSQL?

Comment: @Meem: No, that looks like [the Microsoft variant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175098.aspx) of [`currval()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-sequence.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Create or replace function test(
out sno bigint, 
address varchar,
name varchar default null, 
city varchar default null, 
phonenumber varchar(20) default null)
   returns void as ..
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you just need to reorder just it. In that case your problem will solved. default field must be at bottom.

```
Create or replace function test(
      out sno bigint, 
      ,address varchar
      ,name varchar default null
      ,city varchar default null
      ,phonenumber varchar(20) default null
)
```