# Dynamic ORDER BY and ASC / DESC in a plpgsql function

Tags: postgresql, sql-order-by, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

Following the approach mentioned in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8139618/postgresql-parameterized-order-by-limit-in-table-function/8146245), I want to pass `ORDER BY` and sorting order to a function dynamically.

`ORDER BY` is working fine but I am not able to pass sorting order (`ASC` / `DESC`).

What I have now:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION list(_limit integer,_offset integer,sort_by varchar(100), _order varchar(100),_category varchar(100))
  RETURNS TABLE(
     id INTEGER,
     name VARCHAR,
     clientname VARCHAR,
     totalcount BIGINT
  ) AS
$$
DECLARE
   empty text := '';
BEGIN
RETURN Query EXECUTE
'SELECT d.id,
d.name,
d.clientname,
 count(*) OVER() AS full_count FROM design_list as d 
    where ($5 = $6 Or d.category Ilike $5) 
        ORDER BY ' || quote_ident(sort_by) || ' LIMIT $1 offset $2'
USING _limit,_offset,sort_by, _order,_category, empty;
END;
$$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: I don't get this at all. Why are you mixing concatenation with USING/$ in the same statement? Why are you putting 5 parameters in `USING` when you don't use `$3` and `$4` (sort_by and _order, as it happens)? You ORDER BY `sort_by`, don't use `_order` at all, and say ordering is working and sorting isn't???

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION list(
      _category varchar(100)
    , _limit int
    , _offset int
    , _order_by varchar(100)
    , _order_asc_desc text = 'ASC')  -- last param with default value
  RETURNS TABLE(id int, name varchar, clientname varchar, totalcount bigint)
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
DECLARE
   _empty text := '';
BEGIN
   -- Assert valid _order_asc_desc
   IF upper(_order_asc_desc) IN ('ASC', 'DESC', 'ASCENDING', 'DESCENDING') THEN
      -- proceed
   ELSE
      RAISE EXCEPTION 'Unexpected value for parameter _order_asc_desc.
                       Allowed: ASC, DESC, ASCENDING, DESCENDING. Default: ASC';
   END IF;
   
   RETURN QUERY EXECUTE format(
     'SELECT id, name, clientname, count(*) OVER() AS full_count
      FROM   design_list
      WHERE ($1 = $2 OR category ILIKE $1) 
      ORDER  BY %I %s
      LIMIT  %s
      OFFSET %s'
    , _order_by, _order_asc_desc, _limit, _offset)
   USING _category, _empty;
END
$func$;
```

Core feature: use [**`format()`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT) to safely and elegantly concatenate your query string. Related:

- [INSERT with dynamic table name in trigger function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7914325/insert-with-dynamic-table-name-in-trigger-function/7915100#7915100)
- [Format specifier for integer variables in format() for EXECUTE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22656716/format-specifier-for-integer-variables-in-format-for-execute/22675836#22675836)

`ASC` / `DESC` (or `ASCENDING` / `DESCENDING`) are fixed key words. I added a manual check (`IF ...`) and later concatenate with a simple `%s`. That's *one* way to assert legal input. For convenience, I added an error message for unexpected input and a parameter default, so the function defaults to `ASC` if the last parameter is omitted in the call. Related:

- [Optional argument in PL/pgSQL function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11519410/optional-argument-in-pl-pgsql-stored-procedure/11604187#11604187)
- [ERROR: input parameters after one with a default value must also have defaults in Postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24038195/error-input-parameters-after-one-with-a-default-value-must-also-have-defaults/24072348#24072348)

Addressing [Pavel's valid comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775242/postgresql-dynamic-order-by-and-sorting-with-stored-procedure/49775746#comment86566630_49775746), I concatenate `_limit` and `_offset` directly, so the query is already planned with those parameters.

`_limit` and `_offset` are `integer` parameters, so we can use plain `%s` without the danger of SQL injection. You might want to assert reasonable values (exclude negative values and values too high) before concatenating ...

Other notes:

- Use a consistent naming convention. I prefixed all parameters and variables with an underscore `_`, not just *some*.
- Not using table qualification inside `EXECUTE`, since there is only a single table involved and the `EXECUTE` has its separate scope.
- I renamed some parameters to clarify. `_order_by` instead of `_sort_by`; `_order_asc_desc` instead of `_order`.

Comment: LIMIT, OFFSET are important clauses for optimization - I am not sure if passing these parameters via USING clause can have negative impact on execution plan quality. This is classic example of single query wrapping - important and well known performance antipattern.

Comment: @PavelStehule: Good point. I added an alternative for that as well.

Answer (score 0):

non dynamic sql solution.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION list(
...
in_use_asc boolean default false,
_order_by varchar(100)
..
)
..


CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tempHolder ON COMMIT DROP AS
SELECT SELECT id, name, clientname, count(*) OVER() AS full_count
      FROM   design_list
      WHERE ($1 = $2 OR category ILIKE $1);

     IF in_use_asc = TRUE THEN
        RETURN QUERY SELECT * FROM tempHolder ORDER BY _order_by asc LIMIT {} OFFSET {};
    ELSE 
        RETURN QUERY SELECT * FROM tempHolder ORDER BY _order_by desc LIMIT {} OFFSET {};
    END IF;
```

Shouldnt be any slower because SQL needs to grab everything anyway because of the ORDER BY plus you avoid the dynamic SQL.

Comment: I don't think this will work.  In your `RETURN QUERY`, it will just apply the `ORDER BY` to the literal string value passed in to `_order_by_`, which is a constant value and will thus negate any ordering.  I only mention this because I'm trying to figure out the same problem and tried the same thing you did!