# SQL statement instrumentation?

Tags: sql, postgresql, instrumentation

I was wondering if there is a reliable way to instrument SQL query statements such as

```
SELECT * from table where 1=1;
```

into a new statement like the follows that stores the result relation into a temporary table.

```
SELECT * into temp result from table where 1=1;
```

For this simple statement, I can parse the statement and add `into` clause before `from`. I was just wondering if there are some libraries that can do this for complicated statements with `WITH` etc, so that the end result of a set of query statements is stored into a `result` table.

BTW, I am using PHP/JavaScript with PostgresSQL 9.3.

Thanks.

---

Clarification:

This question is not a duplicate of [Creating temporary tables in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15691243/creating-temporary-tables-in-sql/15700736#15700736) or [Creating temporary tables in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15691243/creating-temporary-tables-in-sql), because those two questions are about SQL grammar/usage issues around creating temporary tables. This question is not about SQL usage but about program instrumentation and whether/how a **sequence** of SQL query statements can be analyzed and transformed to achieve certain effects. So it's not about how to manually write new statements from scratch, but rather about how to transform an **existing** set of statements.

Comment: do you mean like "create table x select * from y" or "insert into x select * from y". These two are completely legal

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15700736/1216680

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating temporary tables in SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15691243/creating-temporary-tables-in-sql)

Comment: This is not a question of SQL usage, but about how to manipulate SQL statements. I'v added clarification why the question is not a duplicate of the above mentioned two questions.