# Select into temp table in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

How to create temporary table using select into in PostgreSQL. For example in SQL `Select * into temp_tab from source_tab;`

Comment: Your question have answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15691243/creating-temporary-tables-in-sql

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You can try to use **[Create Table As](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createtableas.html)** command like this:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE mytable AS
SELECT * from source_tab;
```

From the docs:

> **This command is functionally similar to SELECT INTO**, but it is preferred since it is less likely to be confused with other uses of
>   the SELECT INTO syntax. Furthermore, CREATE TABLE AS offers a superset
>   of the functionality offered by SELECT INTO.
>
> The CREATE TABLE AS command allows the user to explicitly specify
>   whether OIDs should be included. If the presence of OIDs is not
>   explicitly specified, the default_with_oids configuration variable is
>   used.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response...should i use without create temp ....i.e in your example...