# Copy records missing from one table to a new table

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, left-join

I managed to delete 4,000 rows from a table in my 129,000-row production database (Postgres 9.4 on Heroku), but only identified the problem a few days later.

I have a backup from before the loss, but only want to *selectively restore the missing rows* back to the table, preserving their id's. (A complete restore is not an option as new data has since been added to the table.)

Into a local testing database I have imported the backed-up table as `articles_backup`, alongside the actual `articles` table. I want to find all the rows in `articles_backups` that are missing from `articles` and then copy these to a new table `articles_restores` that I will then restore to the production database, back into the `articles` table (preserving record id's).

This query successfully returns all the id's of the deleted records:

```
select articles_backups.id
from articles_backups
left outer join articles on (articles_backups.id = articles.id)
where articles.id is null
```

But I have not been able to copy the result to a new table. I have unsuccessfully tried:

```
select *
into articles_restores
from articles_backups
left outer join articles on (articles_backups.id = articles.id)
where articles.id is null;
```

Which gives:

> ```
> ERROR:  column "id" specified more than once
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically your query with `LEFT JOIN` / `IS NULL` does what you are after:

- [Select rows which are not present in other table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19363481/select-rows-which-are-not-present-in-other-table/19364694#19364694)

You get the error because you select all columns from both tables, and there is an `id` column in both. It's not possible to create a new table with duplicate column names, and it's not what you want to begin with. Only select columns from `articles_backups`:

```
CREATE TABLE articles_restores AS
SELECT ab.*
FROM   articles_backups ab
LEFT   JOIN articles a USING (id)
WHERE  a.id IS NULL;
```

While being at it I simplified your query syntax with table aliases. The `USING` clause is just for the convenience of shorter code. It folds the two `id` columns into one, but all other columns are still in there twice if you `SELECT *`.

Use [`CREATE TABLE AS`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createtableas.html). <strike>`SELECT INTO`</strike> is also defined by the SQL standard and implemented in Postgres, but its use is discouraged. It's used in PL/pgSQL functions for a different purpose. Details:

- [Creating temporary tables in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15691243/creating-temporary-tables-in-sql/15700736#15700736)

Comment: Thanks Erwin. Good references there too.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an [except](http://www.postgresqlforbeginners.com/2010/11/sql-union-except-and-intersect.html) to retrieve all the rows from `articles_backup` that are different from `articles`:

(assuming both tables have the same columns  in the same order)

you could also [create a temp table](http://www.techonthenet.com/postgresql/tables/create_table_as.php) with this info to make it easy on your repairing statements:

```
create table temp_articles as
select * from articles_backup 
except
select * from articles
```

step 1 - update rows from 'articles_backup' present in `articles`.

This step needs attention... you will have to establish a rule to choose between the data present in `articles` and the one present in `temp_articles`.

```
UPDATE articles a
SET a.col1=b.col1,
    a.col2=b.col2,
    (... other columns ...)
FROM (SELECT * FROM  temp_articles) AS b
WHERE a.id = b.id and /* your rule for data to be (or not) updated goes here */
```

step 2 - insert rows from 'articles_backup' not present in `articles` (your deleted records):

```
insert into articles
select * from temp_articles where id not in (select id from articles)
```

Let us know if you need more help.

Comment: Thanks Fabio / great info there, which lead me to being able to restore the missing tables with a few tweaks.