# Why isn't my table being created in Postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3, create-table

My end goal is complete a Postgresql function that will need to use a temporary table. Trying to create the temporary table itself isn't working because of a syntax error. I'm pretty sure I have the syntax right so can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

In PGAdmin III, I open a query window and enter the following:

```
create temporary table tmp_parts
(
  id serial not null,
  part_number character varying(255) not null,
  max_price numeric(19,2) not null
);
```

When I run the Explain Query feature to test the syntax, I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "serial"
LINE 3:   id serial not null,
             ^
********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near "serial"
SQL state: 42601
Character: 98
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your query runs fine when I run it in Postgres 9.3.

Comment: @DJTripleThreat If you want to "test the syntax" in other words execute the query without acctually modification of database, but in the same time be alerted if syntax is good or wrong, you could do within transaction and rollback it. ie.: `START TRANSACTION;  /*then your query*/  ROLLBACK;`

Comment: @Gabriel'sMessanger thanks! I figured that out a couple minutes ago. That is very useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use `create table` in `explain`. Only the [following](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-explain.html) is allowed:

> Any SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, VALUES, EXECUTE, DECLARE, or
>   CREATE TABLE AS statement, whose execution plan you wish to see.

Comment: wow what a bummer! I'd like to check that my code isn't going to do something wonky before I commit it as a function. Thats a little disheartening. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: The reason is that there is no execution plan associated with creating a table, unless there is a DML query component to it, as there is for `create table ... AS ...`. So even if it was valid syntax, there would be no plan to explain.

Answer (score 0):

`serial` is not actually a type in postgres, it is a shorthand for

`id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('tmp_parts_seq')`

My 'guess' is that either it does not like the duplication of `NOT NULL` or  (more likely?) that you can't have a sequence of temporary numbers because they are temporary.

It is simpler than we imagined:

[This previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15691243/creating-temporary-tables-in-sql) shows the syntax, you need to remove the brackets and finish the statement with a semi-colon.

Comment: That was what I thought also but simply changing `serial` to `integer` gave me similar results.