# How to remove duplicate rows with foreign keys dependencies?

Tags: database, postgresql, exception, foreign-keys, plpgsql

I am trying to write a simple stored procedure in PostgreSQL 9.1 that will remove duplicate entries from a parent `cpt` table. The parent table `cpt` is referenced by a child table `lab` defined as:

```
CREATE TABLE lab (
 recid serial NOT NULL,
 cpt_recid integer,
  ........
 CONSTRAINT cs_cpt FOREIGN KEY (cpt_recid)
   REFERENCES cpt (recid) MATCH SIMPLE
   ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE RESTRICT,
 ...
);
```

The biggest problem I'm having is how to obtain the record which failed so that I can use it in the `EXCEPTION` clause to move the children rows from `lab` to one acceptable key, then loop back through and delete the unnecessary records from the `cpt` table.

Here is the (very wrong) code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION h_RemoveDuplicateCPT()
  RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
LOOP
   BEGIN

   DELETE FROM cpt
   WHERE recid IN (
      SELECT recid
      FROM  (
         SELECT recid,
         row_number() over (partition BY cdesc ORDER BY recid) AS rnum
         FROM cpt) t
      WHERE t.rnum > 1)
   RETURNING recid;

   IF count = 0 THEN
      RETURN;
   END IF;  

   EXCEPTION WHEN foreign_key_violation THEN
      RAISE NOTICE 'fixing unique_violation';
      RAISE NOTICE 'recid is %' , recid;
   END;
END LOOP;
END;                    
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

Comment: Have you tried hidden column ctid ? It is helpful with deleting duplicates even when all visible columns are the same.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do this much more efficiently with a **single SQL statement** with [**data-modifying CTEs**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING).

```sql
WITH plan AS (
   SELECT *
   FROM  (
      SELECT recid, min(recid) OVER (PARTITION BY cdesc) AS master_recid
      FROM   cpt
      ) sub
   WHERE  recid <> master_recid  -- ... <> self
   )
 , upd_lab AS (
   UPDATE lab l
   SET    cpt_recid = p.master_recid   -- link to master recid ...
   FROM   plan p
   WHERE  l.cpt_recid = p.recid
   )
DELETE FROM cpt c
USING  plan p
WHERE  c.recid = p.recid
RETURNING c.recid;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=02b927a3d4f4dfa0c6c33f35d8cd7312)*
<sub>Old [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/651b4/3)</sub>

**Much** faster and cleaner. Looping is comparatively expensive, exception handling is comparatively even more expensive.
More importantly, references in `lab` are redirected to the respective master row in `cpt` automatically, which wasn't in your original code, yet. So you can **delete all dupes at once**.

You can still wrap this in a PL/pgSQL or SQL function if you like.

#### Explanation

1. In the 1st CTE `plan`, identify a master row in each partition with the same `cdesc`. In your case the row with the minimum `recid`.
2. In the 2nd CTE `upd_lab` redirect all rows referencing a dupe to the master row in `cpt`.
3. Finally, delete dupes, which is not going to raise exceptions because depending rows are being linked to the remaining master row virtually at the same time.

#### `ON DELETE RESTRICT`

All CTEs and the main query of a *statement* operate on the same snapshot of underlying tables, virtually **concurrently**. They don't see each others' effects on underlying tables:

- [Delete parent if it's not referenced by any other child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15809463/postgresql-using-foreign-keys-delete-parent-if-its-not-referenced-by-any-othe/15810159#15810159)

One might expect a FK constraint with `ON DELETE RESTRICT` to raise exceptions because, [per documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html#id-1.9.3.85.6):

> Referential actions other than the `NO ACTION` check cannot be deferred,
> even if the constraint is declared deferrable.

However, the above statement is a **single command** and, [the manual again](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html#id-1.9.3.85.6):

> A constraint that is not deferrable will be checked immediately after
> every **command**.

Bold emphasis mine. Works for the less restrictive default `ON DELETE NO ACTION` too, of course.

But be wary of concurrent transactions writing to the same tables, but that's a general consideration, not specific to this task.

An exception applies for `UNIQUE` and `PRIMARY KEY` constraint, but that does not concern *this* case:

- [Constraint defined DEFERRABLE INITIALLY IMMEDIATE is still DEFERRED?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10032272/constraint-defined-deferrable-initially-immediate-is-still-deferred)

Comment: How (when) does the upd_lab get executed?

Comment: @AlanWayne: CTE `plan` is executed first, because the other two queries depend on it. The other two are executed in arbitrary order. But all queries see the same snapshot of the underlying tables. Hence "virtually at the same time".

Answer (score 1):

You can select all duplicates once and loop over the result with a record variable.
You'll have access to whole current record. The function below may serve as an example:

```
create or replace function show_remove_duplicates_in_cpt ()
returns setof text language plpgsql
as $$
declare
    rec record;
begin
    for rec in
        select * from (
            select 
                recid, cdesc, 
                row_number() over (partition by cdesc order by recid) as rnum
            from cpt
            ) alias
        where rnum > 1
    loop
        return next format ('fixing foreign key for %s %s %s', rec.recid, rec.cdesc, rec.rnum);
        return next format ('deleting from cpt where recid = %s', rec.recid);
    end loop;
end $$;

select * from show_remove_duplicates_in_cpt ();
```