# Difficulty using CTE's with window PARTITION BY and string pattern matching in PostgreSQL

Tags: database, postgresql, common-table-expression

I'm trying to expand on my understanding of CTE's and window partitions as used by PostgreSQL 9.1. (Example taken from my other question [How to remove duplicate rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30958622/how-to-remove-duplicate-rows-with-foreign-keys-dependencies).) The situation is that `cdesc` is a text field that (from a previous database) had unnecessary characters added to keep each `cdesc` text entry different (and unique).

> The problem is how to combine all entries in table CPT that match the string pattern of "excision/biopsy pathology".

Doing this *fails* since the "plan" is grouping the complete (and unique) `cdesc` - not just the matching part:

```
WITH plan AS (
SELECT recid, cdesc, min(recid) OVER (PARTITION BY cdesc) AS master_recid
FROM cpt
 WHERE cpt.cdesc LIKE '%excision/biopsy pathology%'
   )
, upd_lab AS (
   UPDATE lab l
   SET    cpt_recid = p.master_recid   
   FROM   plan p
   WHERE  l.cpt_recid = p.recid
   AND    p.recid <> p.master_recid  
   )
DELETE FROM cpt c
USING  plan p
WHERE  c.cdesc LIKE '%excision/biopsy pathology%'
AND    c.recid = p.recid
AND    p.recid <> p.master_recid  
RETURNING c.recid;
```

The `lab` table is defined (from the previous question) as:

```
CREATE TABLE lab (
 recid serial NOT NULL,
 cpt_recid integer,
  ........
 CONSTRAINT cs_cpt FOREIGN KEY (cpt_recid)
   REFERENCES cpt (recid) MATCH SIMPLE
   ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE RESTRICT,
 ...
);
```

My questions are:

1. How can string pattern matching be used with the partition, and
2. How does the `upd_lab` update get called to move records in the lab table to the new `master_recid`?

Edit #1:
The following DOES work to do what I need, but I'm still unclear as to how the `upd_lab` cte is being called:

```
WITH plan AS (
   SELECT recid, min(recid) OVER (PARTITION BY cdesc LIKE '%excision/biopsy pathology%') AS master_recid
   FROM cpt
   WHERE cpt.cdesc LIKE '%excision/biopsy pathology%'
   )
, upd_lab AS (
   UPDATE lab l
   SET    cpt_recid = p.master_recid   -- link to master recid ...
   FROM   plan p
   WHERE  l.cpt_recid = p.recid
   AND    p.recid <> p.master_recid  -- ... only if not linked to master
   )
DELETE FROM cpt c
USING  plan p
WHERE  c.cdesc LIKE '%excision/biopsy pathology%'
AND    c.recid = p.recid
AND    p.recid <> p.master_recid  -- ... only if notmaster
RETURNING c.recid;
```

Comment: What do you mean by `but I'm still unclear as to how the upd_lab cte is being called`? You obviously called it and it worked ... Start by [reading the manual here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-with.html).

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter If I understand it correctly, the "With" --both the plan and the upd_lab -- will be executed automatically (without an explicit call in the parent delete) for each row the parent delete accesses. Right? :)

Comment: Almost true. However, data-modifying CTEs are treated differently from simple CTEs (with only `SELECT`). Details : http://stackoverflow.com/a/15810159/939860

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the `partition by`.  The `where` is doing the work you want:

```
WITH plan AS (
      SELECT recid, cdesc, min(recid) OVER () AS master_recid
      FROM cpt
      WHERE cpt.cdesc LIKE '%excision/biopsy pathology%'
   ),
   upd_lab AS (
    UPDATE lab l
       SET    cpt_recid = p.master_recid   
       FROM   plan p
       WHERE  l.cpt_recid = p.recid AND
              p.recid <> p.master_recid  
   )
DELETE FROM cpt c
USING  plan p
WHERE  c.cdesc LIKE '%excision/biopsy pathology%' AND
       c.recid = p.recid AND
       p.recid <> p.master_recid  
RETURNING c.recid;
```

Comment: How is the upd_lab cte being called? Thanks