# Remove duplicates from a table and re-link referencing rows to the new master

Tags: sql, postgresql, duplicates, common-table-expression

I have a table `transcription` which contains passages of transcribed text and their citations with columns:

`text, transcription_id(PK), t_notes, citation`

and the second table `town_transcription` being the relationship table that links places (from another table) referenced in the text to that transcription record. This table has the columns:

`town_id(FK), transcription_id(FK), confidence_interval`

Many of these passages of text reference multiple towns, but stupidly I just duplicated records and linked them individually to each town. I have identified the duplicate rows of text using the following SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM transcription aa
WHERE (select count(*) from transcription bb
WHERE (bb.text = aa.text) AND (bb.citation = aa.citation)) > 1
ORDER BY text ASC;
```

I now have about 2000 rows (2 to 6 duplicates of some text passages) where I need to delete the extra `transcription_id`'s from the `transcription` table and change the `transcription_id` from the relationship table, `town_transcription`, to point to the remaining, now unique, transcription record. From reading other questions, I think utilizing `UPDATE FROM` and `INNER JOIN` might be necessary, but I really don't know how to implement this, I'm just a beginner, thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

This single command should do it all:

```
WITH blacklist AS (  -- identify duplicate IDs and their master
   SELECT *
   FROM  (
      SELECT transcription_id
           , min(transcription_id) OVER (PARTITION BY text, citation) AS master_id
      FROM   transcription
      ) sub
   WHERE  transcription_id <> master_id
   )
, upd AS (  -- redirect referencing rows
   UPDATE town_transcription tt
   SET    transcription_id = b.master_id
   FROM   blacklist b
   WHERE  b.transcription_id = tt.transcription_id
   )
DELETE FROM transcription t  -- kill dupes (now without reference)
USING  blacklist b
WHERE  b.transcription_id = t.transcription_id;
```

For lack of definition I chose the row with the smallest ID per group as surviving master row.

FK constraints don't get in the way unless you have non-default settings. Detailed explanation:

- [How to remove duplicate rows with foreign keys dependencies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30958622/how-to-remove-duplicate-rows-with-foreign-keys-dependencies/30971095#30971095)
- [Delete duplicates and reroute referencing rows to new master](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/220944/3684)

After removing the dupes you might now want to add a `UNIQUE` constraint to prevent the same error from reoccurring:

```
ALTER TABLE transcription
ADD CONSTRAINT transcription_uni UNIQUE (text, citation);
```

Comment: What is the significance of the 'sub' at the end of the first FROM clause?

Comment: Also, the query results in an ERROR:  update or delete on table "transcription" violates foreign key constraint "town_transcription_transcription_id_fkey" on table "town_transcription"
DETAIL:  Key (transcription_id)=(4652) is still referenced from table "town_transcription".

Comment: And when I make an exception in the query for that record, it just counts down to the next one and says the same for 4651, etc. Do I need to blacklist the combination of `town_id` and `transcription_id` since they are a compound key?

Comment: @C.Smith: `sub` is the alias for the table derived in subquery. Every table requires a name.

Comment: @C.Smith: You never mentioned a *compound key*. I assumed an FK to some `town` table for `town_id`. (Error msg seems unrelated either way.) Avoid misunderstandings with `CREATE TABLE` statements (with just relevant columns) showing actual data types and constraints instead of the less helpful pseudo-code you provided. You can only delete rows from `transcription` after all references have been removed. Are you sure, my `blacklist` with `PARTITION BY text, citation` covers *all* instances? Maybe dupes with empty string (`''`) vs NULL or typos slipping through? Or unrelated refs?

Comment: Yes, the `town_id` column is from a separate `town` town table, I just happened to make the combination of it and `transcription_id` a compound primary key in the relationship table, my apologies for the lack of clarity. And regarding the `blacklist` covering all instances, after getting the error, I tried `PARTITION BY text, citation, ref_date, t_notes` afterwards to reduce the possibility of something slipping through. Same error. Some `citation` values are NULL.

Comment: If you provide a test setup in the question with actual `CREATE TABLE` statements and a couple of sample rows, I'll have another look. Maybe a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/) to play with ... And *always* disclose your version of Postgres. `SELECT version()` helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use `row_number() over(...)` to identify rows that repeat information. A `partition by text, citation` in the over clause will force the row number series to re-start at 1 for each unique set of those values:

```
select
     *
from (
       select
              text, transcription_id, t_notes, citation
            , row_number() over(partition by text, citation 
                                order by transcription_id) as rn
       from transcription 
     ) d
where rn > 1
```

Once you have verified those as the unwanted rows,then use the same logic for a delete statement.

However, you may **loose information held in the t_notes column** - are you willing to do that?