# Understanding With query operation

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression

I saw this example in postgresql guide:

```
WITH t AS (
DELETE FROM foo
) 
DELETE FROM bar;
```

The manual says:

> This example would remove all rows from tables foo and bar. The number
>   of affected rows reported to the client would only include rows
>   removed from bar.

Why would it delete from `foo` if I didn't "call" `t`?

Normaly `with` is used like:

```
WITH t AS (
    UPDATE products SET price = price * 1.05
    RETURNING *
)
SELECT * FROM t;
```

There is an actuall call to `t` which only then "summons" the `with` block.

Can someone explain this?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15810159/939860

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quoted example shows that a query in `with` clause is executed regardless of whether it is used in the main query or not. With this principle you can perform several independent operations in a single query. It is a very convenient solution and greatly expands the flexibility of SQL.

Note that if you do not want the query `t` to be executed, just do not use it:

```
 DELETE FROM bar;
```

If you have used

```
 WITH t AS (
 DELETE FROM foo
 )
 DELETE FROM bar;
```

this means that your intention is to remove rows from both tables `foo` and `bar` in one query.

In [the documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/queries-with.html) you can find:

> If a data-modifying statement in WITH lacks a RETURNING clause, then
>   it forms no temporary table and cannot be referred to in the rest of
>   the query. Such a statement will be executed nonetheless.

Comment: It would be helpful if there were quotes from the specification about this behaviour of `WITH` (since at the moment it's not obvious what this answer is based on).

Comment: @zerkms: The explanation in the documentation is adjacent to the cited example ...

Comment: Now it's *the* answer :-)

Comment: So if I write just  `WITH t AS (
 DELETE FROM foo
 )` nothing will happen? correct?

Comment: @UnPeu: Nothing will happen because you'll have a syntax error.