# Execute multiple queries as one dblink transaction

Tags: java, postgresql, dblink

I am working in a Java application where I need to execute these the two queries (as Strings in java) at the same time and rollback the transaction if there where errors.

```
SELECT dblink_exec('hostaddr=xxx.xx.xxx.xxx port=5432 dbname=bdname user=myuser password=mypass connect_timeout=2',
'INSERT INTO table3(field4) 
VALUES (5)') AS result;

SELECT dblink_exec('hostaddr=xxx.xx.xxx.xxx port=5432 dbname=bdname user=myuser password=mypass connect_timeout=2',
'UPDATE table1 SET field2 = field2 + 3.0 WHERE field1 = 16436') AS result;
```

**UPDATE**

I created one String with the two queries separated with `;` as in the comments suggest

**UPDATE**

I have tried JDBC atomic transactions as the code in java. I force the second sql fail but even if I am specifying .setAutoCommit(false); the dblink affected the other database with the first query. I tried the same code with NO dblink transactions and the rollback works well. dblink is the problem.

**Java UPDATE**

```
public static boolean ejecutarTransaccionDblink(String sql) {
    boolean estado = false;
    try {
        Statement sentencia = conexion.createStatement();
        conexion.setAutoCommit(false);
        if (sql.length() != 0) {
            if (sentencia.execute(sql)) {
                conexion.commit();
                estado = true;
            }
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.toString());
        try {
            estado = false;
            conexion.rollback();
        } catch (SQLException ex1) {
        }
    } finally {
        try {
            conexion.setAutoCommit(true);
            return estado;
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            return estado;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: JDBC gives atomic transactions via batches:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/transactions.html

Comment: @EricN I understand that but it is not working with bdlink

Comment: Did you try sending both statements (separated by a `;`) with a single call to `dblink_exec()`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I just tried it. The first query returns "INSERT 0 1" and the second returns "UPDATE 1". I got this exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Multiple ResultSets were returned by the query. Even if I modify my Java code as in the example no value is returned from sentencia.executeQuery(sql);

Comment: you need to use `executeUpdate()` for DML statements, not `executeQuery()`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name new exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: A result was returned by the statement, when none was expected. The funny thing is that even I have that exception the queries where executed... How can I know if they where correctly executed?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I updated the Java code. I can know now when the queries were executed. But I have the same problem, I made the update query fail and the insert query was executed anyway. I think separating the queries with ; in the same string isn't working :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to run the queries in a transaction, you simply need to set the `auto-commit` feature to false on the connection (remembering to set it back to true when you're done, especially if the connection is retrieved from a connection pool - and therefore reused).

The code is relatively simple:

```
ResultSet resultado = null;
String statement1 = "SELECT dblink_exec('hostaddr=xxx.xx.xxx.xxx port=5432 dbname=bdname user=myuser password=mypass connect_timeout=2','INSERT INTO table3(field4) VALUES (5)') AS result";
String statement2 = "SELECT dblink_exec('hostaddr=xxx.xx.xxx.xxx port=5432 dbname=bdname user=myuser password=mypass connect_timeout=2','UPDATE table1 SET field2 = field2 + 3.0 WHERE field1 = 16436') AS result";
    try {
        // set auto-commit to false, to indicate start of transaction
        conexion.setAutoCommit(false);

        // run whatever queries you want on the connection, in a transaction, e.g. :
        Statement sentencia = conexion.createStatement();
        resultado = sentencia.executeQuery(sql);

        //manually commit the transaction when you're done
        conexion.commit();

        return resultado;
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println("Error Consulta:" + ex);

        // ensure transaction is rolled-back in case of error. (note: you might want to add an NPE check here
        con.rollback();
        return null;
    } finally {
        // close any statements / preparedStatements, etc. Note you MUST do this in the finally block, to ensure your connection won't stay in transaction.
        con.setAutoCommit(true);
    }
```

Hope that helps

**UPDATE**

As @a_horse_with_no_name pointed out, dblink_exec connects to a remote db, so the above is not complete, as it only handles transactions in the first db.

I believe the answer should lie with using **named connections** with `dblink_exec` where the process involves:

- opening a new connection with `dblink_connect`
- starting a transaction in new named connection with `dblink_exec`
- executing query 1 with `dblink_exec` in previously opened connection
- executing query 2 with `dblink_exec` in previously opened connection
- committing transaction in previously opened connection

Therefore, the code would look like this:

```
SELECT dblink_connect('myconn','hostaddr=xxx.xx.xxx.xxx port=5432 dbname=bdname user=myuser password=mypass connect_timeout=2');
SELECT dblink_exec('myconn','BEGIN');
SELECT dblink_exec('myconn', 'INSERT INTO table3(field4) VALUES (5)');
SELECT dblink_exec('myconn', 'UPDATE table1 SET field2 = field2 + 3.0 WHERE field1 = 16436');
SELECT dblink_exec('myconn','COMMIT');
```

The thing is, this is all untested, so @KazMiller could you please give this a try?

Comment: But `dblink_exec()` will open a different connection (and thus a different transaction) to the remote host independent of the JDBC connection (and its auto commit setting) the Java code is using.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name good point! Completely missed that dblink_exec actually connects to remote db.. will update answer accordingly

Comment: updated answer above with a different approach, after @a_horse_with_no_name ' comment... Kaz, could you please give this a try?

Comment: using dblink named connections, don't forget to close it: `SELECT dblink_close('myconn');`

Comment: ...I meant `SELECT dblink_disconnect('myconn')`

Answer (score 1):

If all else fails, chain multiple SQL commands into one using one or more **CTEs**:

```
WITH upd AS (
  UPDATE table1 SET field2 = field2 + 3.0 WHERE field1 = 16436
  )
INSERT INTO table3(field4) 
VALUES (5)') AS result;
```

Or `INSERT` first, does not matter. Typically it wouldn't make sense to chain two unrelated commands this way, but it's a clean application of the feature. You can chain as many commands as you like this way. You just cannot have two commands writing to the same *row*. You can even have a final `SELECT` return related or unrelated values. Unlike `SELECT` in CTEs, all data-modifying CTEs are always executed to completion. [The manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING):

> Data-modifying statements in `WITH` are executed exactly once, and
>   **always to completion**, independently of whether the primary query reads
>   all (or indeed any) of their output. Notice that this is different
>   from the rule for `SELECT` in `WITH`: as stated in the previous section,
>   execution of a `SELECT` is carried only as far as the primary query
>   demands its output.

Related:

- [PostgreSQL: using foreign keys, delete parent if it's not referenced by any other child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15809463/postgresql-using-foreign-keys-delete-parent-if-its-not-referenced-by-any-othe/15810159#15810159)

---

Another option would be to create a **function** (`LANGUAGE sql` or `LANGUAGE plpgsql` - but any language should do) on the target server to encapsulate any number of commands in a single transaction:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_wrapper()
  RETURNS void AS
$func$
   UPDATE table1 SET field2 = field2 + 3.0 WHERE field1 = 16436;
   INSERT INTO table3(field4) VALUES (5);
$func$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

Then:

```
SELECT dblink_exec('hostaddr=xxx.xx.xxx.xxx port=5432 dbname=bdname user=myuser password=mypass connect_timeout=2',
'SELECT f_wrapper()') AS result;
```

You can create (and drop) a function on the fly or persist one that takes parameters for values.