# Doing either SELECT or INSERT

Tags: sql, postgresql, concurrency

I want to write something like a `CASE` statement in PostgreSQL in such a way that I want to `SELECT` from a table, and if nothing is found I want to `INSERT` into the table instead.

My example table `allocated_ideas` looks like this:

```
challenge_id | user_id    | idea_id        | round | is_completed
-------------+------------+----------------+-------+-------------
 '5d956daa'  | '9afbca19' | '3798826ae522' |   5   | false
```

And I want to do something like this in a SQL function:

```
SELECT EXISTS (
SELECT 1 from allocated_ideas ai
where ai.user_id = '9afbca19' 
and ai.challenge_id = '5d956daa'
    and ai.is_completed is false
```

If this condition is true, return the `idea_id`. Otherwise, insert values into the table. Pseudo-code:

```
if (above query is true) {
    SELECT idea_id from allocated_ideas ai 
    where ai.user_id = '9afbca19' 
    and ai.challenge_id = '5d956daa'
        and ai.is_completed is false 
} else {
  INSERT VALUES INTO allocated_ideas('67879', '46578', '978798', 6, false)
}
```

Comment: Some more sample table data would be fine. And _specify_ the expected result.

Comment: There are no `CASE` or `IF` statements in SQL, only in PL/pgSQL. You could use a UNION with CTE with an `INSERT` with a `RETURNING` clause in SQL. But I wonder why the numbers in your `SELECT` and you `INSERT` differ. That would lead to the `INSERT` being constantly executed when the statement is run, unless **somewhere else** the right values are inserted. Is that really what you intend?

Answer (score 3):

**Without concurrent write load** on the table, you can simply:

```
WITH sel AS (
   SELECT idea_id
   FROM   allocated_ideas
   WHERE  user_id = '9afbca19' 
   AND    challenge_id = '5d956daa'
   AND    is_completed IS false 
   )
, ins AS (
                             -- spell out target columns!
   INSERT INTO allocated_ideas (challenge_id, user_id, idea_id, round, is_completed)
   SELECT '67879', '46578', '978798', 6, false
   WHERE  NOT EXISTS (TABLE sel)               -- only when sel is empty!
   -- RETURNING idea_id                        -- unused
)
TABLE sel;
```

The data-modifying CTE `ins` is always executed to completion, even though it is not referenced in the final main command. (A simple `SELECT` wouldn't be executed without being referenced.) See:

- [Delete parent if it's not referenced by any other child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15809463/delete-parent-if-its-not-referenced-by-any-other-child/15810159#15810159)

If you omit target columns for the `INSERT`, it can silently (or noisily) break!

You did not specify to return the new `idea_id` from the `INSERT`. If you need it, you may also want to be able to tell cases apart. I added the column `op` for that purpose:

```sql
WITH sel AS (
   -- like above
, ins AS (
   -- like above
   RETURNING idea_id                        -- used now
   )
SELECT 'sel' AS op, * FROM sel
UNION ALL
SELECT 'ins' AS op, * FROM ins;
```

The query can only ever return a single row, and the `INSERT` is executed in any case (doing nothing if `sel` finds a row), so we do not need `LIMIT 1`.

Typically, there can be **concurrent write load**, though, and you'd want to avoid race conditions. See:

- [Is SELECT or INSERT in a function prone to race conditions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15939902/is-select-or-insert-in-a-function-prone-to-race-conditions/15950324#15950324)

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it using Common Table Expressions (CTEs):

```
WITH sel AS (
    SELECT challenge_id, user_id, idea_id, round, is_completed
    FROM allocated_ideas
    WHERE user_id = '9afbca19' AND challenge_id = '5d956daa' AND is_completed = FALSE
), ins as (
    INSERT INTO allocated_ideas (challenge_id, user_id, idea_id, round, is_completed)
    SELECT '67879', '46578', '978798', 6, FALSE
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (TABLE sel)
    RETURNING *
)
SELECT * FROM sel
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM ins
```

Be aware that this only works if there are no concurrent transactions modifying the table. If you expect concurrent writes, try an INSERT with ON CONFLICT first.